How to plausibly delay the creation of the telescope
I have an alternate Earth with the caveat that outer space is an eldritch horror. If a human peers at the starry sky closely enough, they lose their mind and become a part of it so it'd be game over for Earth. Since that wouldn't suit my worldbuilding needs, I need a plausible reason to delay the creation of powerful telescope beginning at the 1600s and ending at around WW2(or at least an analogous war).
If possible, I want an answer based on material conditions. Note 'alternate Earth' so I'll allow slight alterations on Earth if your answer requires it as long as Earth remains Earth-y. I won't consider answers reliant on chance or human choice like: they didn't think to invent it, the inventors died before they could release it, or telescopes do exist but astronomers coincidentally never use it to look upwards.

Telescopes were invented to make distant objects appear closer on Earth. Almost all telescopes are used to look at distant things on Earth, not at things in the sky. (Almost all as in 99.99% of them.) This is also true historically. Delaying the development of the telescope would have massive effects on navigation, cartography, artillery, photography and so on.

If you need to stop people looking at the sky, why isn't it a sufficient answer to say that after the first guy to point his telescope at the sky went stark raving mad, everybody else decided to not do that? If your problem is that there can't be telescopes on earth (see AlexP's comment), you'll need a reason unconnected to your sky monster.

When you say "become a part of it" do they go up, ascending to the heavens and leaving the rest of humanity alone, or stay in place, becoming in effect a gaping hole in reality that will consume the entirety of humanity in one fell swoop?

Is it enough to delay the invention of the reflecting telescope? It superseded the refracting telescope during the 19th C, because there is a limit to how large and achromatic a lens of perfectly homogeneous glass can be. The refracting telescope can resolve the Milky Way into stars, it cannot resolve Andromeda Galaxy. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leviathan_of_Parsonstown#Operation

If it is not, then (probable) frame challenge. It is hard to imagine how transatlantic navigation can develop w/out specialized telescopes, in particular spyglasses and sextants; the latter must, almost by definition, be pointed at celestial bodies.

Lots of sailors used the North star for navigation

@FrançoisJurain Sextants don't really magnify, and spyglasses can be useful but aren't really necessary for navigation.

@Beanluc indeed, navigation started (tens of? ) thousands of yrs before the spyglass. Transatlantic navigation is where you cannot do w/out nautical charts: meaning drawing them, correcting them and finding your longitude by comparing them with the foreign coast you're spying from afar is key to not losing your ship on landing it.

See "Anathem,"  Neal Stephenson

"If a human peers at the starry sky closely enough, they lose their mind and become a part of it so it'd be game over for Earth." We're missing important context here. What do you mean that they lose their mind and "become part of it"? Why does a single person going mad, result in "game over" for earth?
Seems like if one look at the sky one time was "game over" then life would never have evolved past the most basic sentient creatures with optic nerves. Please elaborate!

" cloud cover "

Much stronger atmospheric turbulence makes it so that without adaptive optics or out of atmosphere telescopes any observation directed at the sky returns nothing meaningful. Only short range observations are intelligible. Imagine the sky looking like a sanded glass: you see vague contours of something on the other side, but cannot really say what it is.
Therefore when the alt-Galileo of your world first points the telescope toward the sky, he sees only a blurry nonsense and opt for spending his nights in a different way.

... Which would make celestial navigation impossible with all that implies for the development of human civilization.

Not necessarily. There are glass types, for example used for bathroom windows, which let light through but distort images sufficiently. Through my window, I can distinguish several street lights outside at night, but not recognize the face of my neighbor standing 50 cm from it. You might well be able to see stars as blurry disks, so you distinguish star formations, but still not see anything but blurry light sources.

@GuntramBlohm: Celestial navigation does not work with blurry patches of light. A standard nautical sextant can measure angles to 0.1 arc-minute. (And stars are feeble light sources; blurring them will make them basically invisible.)

@AlexP Not an issue. Atmospheric turbulence is zero-mean, so you can centroid your blurry patch. Besides, 0.1 arc-minutes is way more than you need, that's 0.1 nm. If it's a 1-degree patch of light, you get 60 nm, which is fine for navigating across the sea.

@user71659: Position is completely irrelevant in the middle of the ocean. Position becomes critically important close to the shore, where the rocks and the reefs are. A precision to within 60 miles is completely useless; for example, the distance between Dover and Calais is only 25 miles, and you need to fit between them. But anyway, the major imprecision came from the chronometers. The sextants were made precise specifically in order to avoid amplifying the errors of chronometers; after a week at sea even the best 20th century chronometer would drift enough to match those 0.1 arc-seconds.

@AlexP That's completely absurd that somebody would use astrogation as their sole means of navigation in the English channel and somehow crash into England or France because of it. Ask the Vikings or Magellan where his harbor charts were. And if you want to be pedantic, GPS wasn't enough to navigate harbors, we had to use DGPS, so forget about astrogation.

@user71659: When you are coming from across the ocean you absolutely must fit in the English Channel by celestial navigation. But if their chronometers were broken, they did not give up, and just fell back to previous methods of navigation. (For example, with a good sextant you can approach by following a line of latitude, taking care to wait until you have good weather, and turn when you see the landmarks.) You are right that people have navigated across the seas without chronometers; it is perfectly possible, it is just slower, riskier and more incovenient.

@AlexP I have no idea why you bring chronometers in. My point is with high atmospheric turbulence, celestial navigation is not impossible because you simply centroid the blurry patch of light. That doesn't change because science says turbulence is a zero-mean phenomenon. People use sextants on the sun and that's about 1/2 degree wide. And even if you don't bother, you can still navigate across the ocean, a degree blur is still good enough.

This is a Frame Challenge
What, specifically, do you mean by "closely enough?"

Earth-based telescopes still can't see the flags and other equipment left on the Moon.
Humans thought there were canals on Mars until the Mariner IV probe took pictures of the planet in 1964.
Telescopes must be focused on something to see it. We are sometimes fooled when using (e.g.) a set of binoculars in that if something is far enough away the maximum focus setting is used and everything past that point is more-or-less in focus. But that's not actually true. Focus a professional telescope on Mars and then try to look at Jupiter. The idea of canals on Mars didn't come about until the mid-1850s (it took that long to get telescopes that could see the planet that clearly), so why delay telescopes from the 1600s? Why worry about it at all?

In other words, your question appears to be the proverbial tempest in a teapot. Anybody who would be driven mad by looking at the heavens with a telescope would be driven mad by simply looking up. No Earth-bound telescope brings the heavens that much closer. Why? In the words of the immortal Douglas Adams...

Space is big. You just won't believe how vastly, hugely, mind-bogglingly big it is. I mean, you may think it's long way down the road to the chemist's, but that's just peanuts to space.

So either...

Your maddening view requires looking at exactly the right spot. (Which is true for any effort to look at a planet, if you think about it. The odds of randomly looking at the sky with a telescope and seeing, e.g., Saturn is remarkably low.)

Your maddening view encompasses a large portion of the sky (look at that quote from Douglas Adams and really think about how big your view would need to be to do this... even if it was only at the orbit of the Moon).

Your maddening view needs only to be noticed and not actually seen. Focus doesn't matter (but now we're back to not needing a telescope to be driven mad).

Your maddening view can't be much beyond the orbit of Mars or it really can't be seen in any kind of detail at all until the mid 1900s (if even then).


Conclusion
You need to abandon the idea that the existence of telescopes matters in terms of the general population. Ignoring the massive and catastrophic consequences to human history if we delay the development of telescopes for any reason (you don't have an alternate-earth at that point, you simply don't have earth), the simple reality is that if a 1600s telescope pointed arbitrarily at the sky would drive someone mad, so would simply looking at the sky. Unless the maddening view is breathtakingly huge and yet still not collapsing into a black hole (because it doesn't have the low density of a nebula), it simply can't be seen arbitrarily in any direction.
I therefore recommend that you make this an issue of just one point in space and pick your starting year for when the telescopes become good enough to focus on that one point and drive people mad. Declare it to be so (frankly, this isn't as unreasonable as you might think) and move on. Frankly, I think it adds to your story to include the mystery of what's causing a vanishingly small number of telescope users to go mad. Nobody may even know the telescope is involved until some astronomer was bright enough to write down, "I'm looking here next."

Just to be clear, both Mars and Jupiter are "at infinity" as far as optics is concerned. If somehow we could arrange for Mars and Jupiter to fit together in the field of view of the telescope, they would appear equally in focus. But the field of view of an astronomical telescope is very narrow and they never fit in it at the same time, so that we need to move the telescope from pointing to Mars to point to Jupiter, and this often changes the position of where the infinity focus is on the focusing knob. (Even on binoculars, where "infinity" is for JBH might not be where it is for AlexP.)

@AlexP Sonofagun. I haven't had to worry about it since my college astronomy class 35 years ago, but I thought I'd been taught that an observatory-grade telescope had a focusing difference between planets in the solar system. Do observatory-grade telescopes have no focusing aparatus at all?

Of course they do. Focus needs to be adjusted to account for all kinds of reasons, for example variations in temperature.

I don't follow the central premise here. The statement "anybody who would be driven mad by looking at the heavens with a telescope would be driven mad by simply looking up" seems to imply that "there is nothing you can see with a telescope that you couldn't see with the naked eye", which clearly isn't true. This seems like saying the fact that you can read the text on a distant sign with a telescope necessarily means you can also read it with the naked eye.

@NuclearHoagie The premise is either (a) the problem is so vast and so easily seen that a telescope is irrelevant or (b) the problem is so hard to see, requiring a telescope, that it doesn't represent a threat to the average citizen using a telescope.

It may be that the eldritch horrors need to be discernible to affect the viewer. Like, it's normal stars, but if you look with a telescope, there's... things crawling between them, arrrgh!

@JBH Not necessarily. I imagine it could be a bit like looking closely at what you thought was a dark-painted wall, and finding out that it's actually crawling with roaches. What if the entire sky is painted with eldritch runes too small to be noticed? The problem is vast, not visible without a telescope, yet impossible to miss with one.

@NuclearHoagie I can only work with what the OP tells me. I point out that if there's something out there physical, then that kind of coverage would collapse into a black hole - it's a LOT of mass. If it's something else, then we need the OP to explain what that something else is. (Although I like the idea of the entire sky painted with eldritch runes... but you do run into AlexP's concern that it would eliminate celestial navigation causing a HUGE divergence from human history.)

@JBH An eldritch horror is an unknowable entity that usually defies physical logic - I don't really see why we'd need to put any constraints at all on its physical form. Maybe it's a thin translucent shell that surrounds earth. This answer seems to suppose that we're talking about a relatively normal object floating around in space, which is a very limiting view. We're not, the OP tells us that outer space itself is the eldritch horror, and by being eldritch, pretty much by definition has some characteristics that do not fit with the natural world.

@NuclearHoagie Once again, I can only work with what the OP tells me. I can't read his/her mind and I don't put words in his/her mouth. The purpose of a Frame Challenge is to point out possible issues with the basic premise and identify how they could be resolved.

Make crystal Glass much more difficult to create or obtain
This is the simple answer.
Clear crystal glass was created in the 1600s using the addition of lead: Details here
This both made it clear and increased the working time - allowing much more industrialized production of Glass.
If you break this aspect (either by restricting the availability of Lead or just saying that this process doesn't work) - then you stop Glass from being clear and thus being made into lenses.
MASSIVE WORLD BUILDING CAVEAT
The problem with this is think about how many inventions are dependent on crystal glass - Magnifying glasses, Microscopes, Mirrors - everything from Biology to the splitting of light - all of these were done with glassware. I mean, even reading glasses and the effect of having a proportion of the population able to read and absorb knowledge who otherwise would not be able to.
And even if you say 'oh well, I will have Glass readily available I will just use a different method' - you cannot have a telescope without those components - and that breaks your rule about simply not inventing it.
My closing suggestion
A Single scientists looking too deep and going mad is very easy to deal with or kill off - but if you look at when Hobby Telescopes started to become popular (around the 1920s) then you can push that event out to suit your story needs: have WW1 last a bit longer so that there is no roaring 20s and then the great depression hits, then WW2 - then hobby Telescopes are a thing - and regular folks all over the world go mad.

To avoid lead being readily available, have its observationally stable isotopes be unstable, with reasonably long half-lives - say, a few thousand years. That will make lead a very rare element, which will have other worldbuilding effects, but they're probably less drastic than the absence of telescopes and microscopes.

"You cannot have a telescope without those components": Oh yes you can. Lead was used because it was very widely available and very cheap. However, making lead a rare element will be very very bad for human civilization; it was very widely used up to the end of the 20th century. It is a very versatile material, and the 21st century drop in the use of lead is due to its bad odor in popular culture.

@AlexP And that fact that it, y'know, actually does drive us mad

@AlexP - I think I perhaps wasnt clear - I wasn't referring to Lead as the component - I meant: things like Lenses, magnifying lenses, eyepieces etc.

@NoName: Yes, it does drive us mad if we eat it or breathe it in large quantities; but it is perfectly safe to touch it. The use of tetra ethyl lead as a fuel additive was a crime against humanity, and what angers me it had been known to be criminal since the 1960s. But on the other hand, the use of lead in optical glass and in solder was benign, because we do not eat photographic lenses or electric circuit boards. At least most of us don't.

@AlexP Lenses I'll grant you. Solder, though... their is a hobbyist circuit board community, and solder releases fumes when used. If you're wearing the proper masks and have the proper ventilation, it's safe, but that's a big if, and lead-free solder gets rid of all those headaches - including the literal one from improper exposure

Doesn't work: the reflector telescope came after the refractor about 30 years. We deal with the same problem today: it's hard to make large glass at much of the wavelengths scientists are interested in (IR and UV), so we keep making reflectors. Other good reasons include no chromatic aberration, reflectors naturally fold in on themselves, only the front surface of a reflector is optically important (you can use carbon fiber behind it). See JWST, Hubble, ELT, GMT, LBT, etc.

@JohnDallman If you modify the radioactivity, you're playing with fundamental constants. Some stories can survive that, others don't, depending on how hard the science needs to be.

@toolforger: No dispute there at all.

Development of the movable-type printing press, firearms (lead bullets) and low-cost metal dinnerware (aka pewter) will be significantly delayed without lead.

Frame Challenge: Your setting solves this problem on its own
Decent optical glass took a lot of effort and government funding to invent as it was. But it's gets even harder to research a technology that makes anyone who uses it magically disappear.  People will not understand why telescopes make people vanish, but everyone who owns one will sooner rather than latter think to point it upwards and they will be gone without ever being able to tell anyone what they did to make it happen.
Or worse, they will tell people, but then not be around anymore to confirm what they found making it look a lot like false news when anyone tries to confirm that the invention exists.  So, the whole thing will look like a matter of tall-tails and charlatans: especially if the telescope disappears with the observer.
Just imagine the stores that would emerge: magical crystals that let you see far away but if you use it you blink out of existence?  In the age of Enlightenment, this would sound like total BS and get tosed in the same bucket of nonsense as the Philosopher's Stone, Panacea, or the medium of Eternal Youth.  This would make getting and keeping funding for optics research much harder if the growing scientific community can't split the "magic" from the "science".  So instead of a concentrated, well managed and financed effort to pursue optics research, the research that does exist will only exist at the fringes of society by people who are mocked for trying to invent something that everyone knows is just a story... and when those guys do disappear, everyone already thinks they are untrustworthy; so, people just assume it's all a con.

I think you started on the right lines there, but then went the wrong way. Astronomy isn't a purely solo endeavour, it generally involves a bunch of people, so if someone suddenly vanished then it'd definitely be noticed. The same as chemists discovering compounds that are unexpectedly explosive, the rest of their team will figure out the pattern and make sure the world knows about it. It's not "magic" if it's well-documented fact.

@Graham It's not a question of if the team will figure it out, it is a question about if the world will go on to make telescopes.  If people who study optics in 1600 start disappearing, and the Church comes in and says they were practicing witchcraft; so, they were smited because their field of study offends God, and Atheists refuse to believe in smiting; so, they deny the event's truth, then by the 1700s its study may be ridiculed, illegal, and sacreligious; so, by the 1900s it's just a fairytales who's exact details are lost like Roman concrete or Damascus Steel.

That chain of events doesn't make sense though.  We're living in a world where the Church already said that people studying optics were practicing witchcraft and offended God, but it didn't make anyone deny the truth of what anyone saw down a telescope.  If there's solid evidence of people studying optics and disappearing, it doesn't matter in the slightest what the Church says, because that solid evidence still exists and the rest of the world will carry on regardless of what the Church says.  It won't even cause a minor delay.

@Nosajimiki astronomical telescopes are just oversized nautical telescopes that you connecting to a tripod and point upwards.  The Church wouldn't be able to enforce a ban on them, since they're so useful to governments and commerce.

People pointing their telescopes upwards will typically have assistants, who'll then witness what happened. So there will be no mystery, just general knowledge that pointing a telescope up is a Bad Idea for some unfathomable reason. People will then start experimenting with animals made to gaze through a telescope to find out what's going on.

It's considered blasphemy.
The first commandment of a major family of religions in your world:
Thou shalt not look upon the face of God.
(And God is thought to exist, if only figuratively, in the sky). A quick glance up at the night sky for navigation is fine, but staring up there with a telescope? The church would never fund a project like that... and scientific progress has historically almost always been funded by religion.
Even as religion develops and theologians stop picturing God as something which literally exists up there, using a powerful telescope to scour the night sky would be thought of as deeply insulting.
(Plus, it's fairly easy to imagine how this would come about - ancient folklore of "don't look too closely at the sky, it'll kill you" gets incorporated into religion as "don't look too closely at the sky, God will kill you.")
I understand that this isn't the material answer you were looking for, but I'd imagine most material answers (eg difficulty producing glass) would have fairly major unwanted consequences for other parts of your world. This should be more self-contained.

I beg to object: the Church would ABSOLUTELY found such a project, possibly in a limited, circumspected, "Papal Exception, valid for 1(one) act of Blasphemy" way because not studying the sky with instruments better than just naked eye is kinda bull... just for the people lookin disappearing and then the Church going hardcore on "DO NOT LOOK AT THE SKY WITH [censorum] INSTRUMENTS!!" teachings.

No need for super complex or far-fetched setups and ideas:
Just have near-constant cloud cover or a translucent sky (during night)
Clear nights are a once-a-millenia event (in any inhabiteable areas / climate zones), which is when everyone with a telescope goes mad and the technology is shunned by the survivors.
Telescopes would still be developed for cartography and all the other earth-observing use cases but unless an expedition brings one of these insanely expensive (and delicate) instruments to the poles (where you can have clear sky), nothing happens.
Implementation ideas: permanent (upper athmosphere) sand/dust storms or just regular old clouds(I know the link isn't perfect but not that far fetched, just look at other planets in our solar system. 100% cloud cover for millenia.
Alternatively: Multiple suns or an incredibly bright moon to drown out any interstellar light. If your eldritch abomination is dark on top of it nobody would have a chance at spotting it. Neighboring planets, moons and the brightest of stars would be observable but not much else (especially not a near-completely-dark void entity). Just think of how much less you see IRL with just a minor city's light pollution, you don't need to turn it up that much to get the effect. And if the light isn't coming from the ground but from (vaguely) where you want to look it takes even less brightness. Especially when combined with a permanently "foggy" upper athmosphere (from my first recommendation, they combine perfectly).

bingo "cloud cover" was my thought !

Religious taboo is the only thing I can come up with. “Thou shall not look to the sky with aught but thine own eyes — doing so disrespects God.” Or some such. The other answers properly rule out physical or scientific limits. It’s pretty easy to imagine how such a taboo gets established: a couple ancient Egyptians playing around with foggy glass catch a glimpse of Beyond, appear to be cursed by gods, and then that story is embedded in all future civilizations.

I started thinking of the plot line of Isaac Asimovs Nightfall where there are multiple nearby stars causing a perpetual day-light and thus no stars to observe.
Eventually night falls,  and perhaps a similar line of story could lead to a late development of telescopes.

Redesign the humans, not the telescope. Give human visual cortex a glitch that makes it impossible to focus your sight in a way that would allow you to use a telescope meaningfully. Maybe not even make it impossible, just give humans extreme vertigo when they try to use any kind of magnification device with a focus point grossly different from a naked human eye; like maybe you get a headache and nausea when you use a simple small spyglass or a simple magnifying glass, but anything that would let you see the celestial bodies clearly would drive you mad on its own, regardless of the Eldritch Horrors.
In fact, this could be enough explanation for Eldritch Horrors on its own. Maybe the horror is purely epistemological, Its not about Perceiving the Horror, Perception IS the Horror.

Frame challenge:
Do you really need a world without telescopes, or just one without telescopes in widespread mainstream use?
I want to offer an alternative: In today's pop culture, the steam age is also the age of the mad scientists. What if, because of telescopes, many of those scientists actually ARE mad?
All you need is the general public not staring into outer space, and that's not really a change, because honestly, how many people do that, even today, with pretty good telescopes available for cheap? Before automation, when telescopes were still precision instruments made by hand, most people couldn't afford one or wouldn't spend the money on something they'd anyway not do often.
Except, of course, for scientists. And that's why the steam age had so many mad scientists.
